# Advice regarding either a web based FTP or a File Sending service

Tags: php, file, ftp, file-upload

I could use some advice.

I'm building a website in which the general user needs to be able to transfer files to the site administrator.  It could be done one of two ways:

1] Some kind of web based interface - PHP perhaps - to send files to the FTP.  I've done some Googling but have yet to come up with anything concrete that works.  I've considered using an Applet but I need something free.  Also, it seems to me that people are hesitant to give Applets permission to run in their browser.

2] Some kind of file transfer service.  I've looked at services like Megaupload but using a free account, the files are public and that will not work.  I need something that a user could use to send a file to the administrator who could pick it up later.

If anyone has some suggestions, it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do file upload via http if you have enough space (which I assume since you also have access to a ftp server). See [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) for more information.

Comment: The tricky spot is that I need to distinguish between unique users without maintaining a database or something like SSL.  

That page you linked to says "This script is for education purposes only. We do not recommend placing this on a web page viewable to the public."  This is a public website and there are definitely security concerns that the owner of the site doesn't want to deal with.